# React useEffect hook doesn't clear interval

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple count down timer using react hooks to count down 3 seconds. But after 3 seconds UI stop rendering but in console.log I can still is prints out every second. Why is the second array parameter in useEffect doesn't prevent this from happening?

[code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-snow-teun1?file=/src/index.js)

```js
function CounterGame() {
  const [timeout, setTimeout] = React.useState(3);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let id = window.setInterval(() => {
      if (timeout > 0) {
        setTimeout(x => x - 1 );
      }
      // this line keep executing even it timeout reach 0
      console.log("in setInterval", timeout);
    }, 1000)

    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [timeout])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      See instructions.
      <h1>{timeout} seconds</h1>
      {!timeout && <button>Click</button>}
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<CounterGame />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup):

> This is why React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time.

Based on this, I believe that the cleanup function is not run until the next iteration of the `useEffect`. In your example, after `timeout` hits 0, the `useEffect` will run 1 more time, setting up a new interval, but because `timeout` is 0, it will not update the state, so the `useEffect` won't be called on the next render. That means the cleanup function never gets called for that last iteration.

Answer (score 5):

This may works for you:

clearIntervel when timeOut is zero by adding condition in useEffect

```
React.useEffect(() => {
      let id = window.setInterval(() => {
        if (timeout > 0) {
          setTimeout(x => x - 1 );
        }

    //clearIntervel here
        if(timeout == 0){
            window.clearInterval(id);
        }

        // this line keep executing even it timeout reach 0
        console.log("in setInterval", timeout);
      }, 1000)
  
      return () => {
        window.clearInterval(id);
      }
    }, [timeout])
```

Comment: Yeah, your changes work. But my main concern is why the last clean up functino clearInterval failed to achieve the same effect

Comment: I think clearIntervel in return function will clear previous Interval and if condition where timeout == 0 will clear current Interval.